# Using DirectX 11, getting message: Shader model 3.0 or better graphic device required

Tags: technical-issues, dragon-ball-xenoverse, directx-11

Direct X 11 is supposed to have Shader 5.0, so why is this happening when I try to run Dragonball: Xenoverse?

I am running the following setup:

---

### System Information

- Operating System: Windows 8.1 64-bit
- System Model: HP ENVY m6 Notebook PC
- BIOS: F.18
- Processor: AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7,
- Memory: 6144MB RAM
- Available OS Memory: 5090MB RAM
- DirectX Version: DirectX 11

I have tried updating all drivers in Device manager, and Windows says all are up to date. When I try launching the game, a black screen comes up, but nothing starts. Alt Tabing out shows there is an error window saying "Video Device Critical Error" and in the grey of the box "Shader model 3.0 or better graphic device required.

Shader model 5.0 is supposed to come on DirectX11, so I don't understand the problem. How should I proceed?

Comment: You need to clean up the question. A DxDiag should be complementary to the question, not the question itself. We shouldn't have to look for your system specs between lines of a report, you should provide them.

Comment: Alright. What system specs do I need to include? The part under the heading "System Information" has alot of the things I thought would be needed. What's missing?

Comment: It's not about what's missing. It's about making a proper question. questions must be clear, and concrete. [Here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209578/extreme-fps-drop-in-counter-strike-global-offensive/) is a good example of a question about technical issues. And telling us the full name of the game would be useful. I suspect you're speaking about DragonBall:Xenoverse, though you don't specify it.

Comment: Ok, I have tried to make it more clear.

Comment: Much better, (y). You're still not giving us a video card model though, I suspect you're using an integrated one?

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know how to check that. I thought the FX7500 was supposed to have GPU cores in it, isn't that what "Radeon R7" is?

Comment: Yep, that is an integrated video card, a CPU with GPU cores in it, so it does appear to have integrated video. [This](http://h20386.www2.hp.com/CanadaStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=G6R80UA&opt=ABL&sel=PCNB#merch-tech-specs) is your laptop, am I correct? Minimum requirements for that game state external video cards. The game appears to be a bit demanding for an integrated GPU, so I'd say your laptop may not support it. Do you have any other games we could compare?

Comment: Im afraid not. It's a new computer. So does that mean I need to buy another graphics card in addition to the integrated one to play?

Comment: Is not that easy. Laptops are quite stiff. You can replace RAM's and HDD's but not video cards. Almost sure the game is just a bit too much for the card to handle. [This](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/2533/radeon-r7-graphics.html) is you GPU, It's a low profile one.

Comment: Games often try to recognize video cards based on strings the hardware or driver returns. This string will be validated against some specified pattern and then the game engine knows whats the card able to do. A common problem with laptop cards are that they are returning some weird strings and the game think is is not compatible even if it is. This would be a fault of the game and not of your hardware which is definitivly shadermodel 5 compatible.

Comment: @EvilFonti Weird string = weird card = not compatible. Just because a card meet specifications it doesn't mean it should be compatible. Given how integrated video cards work, there are some things you just can't run with them.