# CS GO, fps drop

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive

**Computer specs:**
    - 16Gb of RAM
    - intel core i7 4710HQ
    - intel HD graphics 4600
    - 1 Tb of memory

Ok, so I did alot of researching, and found this question. [Question for fps drop](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209578/extreme-fps-drop-in-counter-strike-global-offensive?newreg=17561e108fd84e89a59859e14682f447)

And I literally have the exact problem and symptoms. But my fps is 120, instead of 250. If you don't know, my fps drops to the 40's.
And after 3-4 days (**maybe even 1-2**), it goes back to 120 fps. The problem for that question, was a broken card. But my fps refixes it's self (after time) so that can't be it, right? I really can't afford a new card (and I have a laptop, and it's integrated into the CPU), mostly because my GPU is a **Intel HD graphics 4600**, so I usually thought when this was first happening that there was an update or a bug that messes with Intel GPU cards.

I don't really know how to fix this. What to try and fix. I mean I looked at the question, And I have the exact problem, with my fps dropping to the 40's, and when I shoot or do things, it lowers.

Should I get a new APU? (I don't know how either to put it on, I'm poor, can't afford the core i7 4710HQ processor either) Should I try some fixes? or should I just wait it out like the last couple times?

EDIT: turns out it's for most of my games..

Comment: VAC and CS:GO's really badly sound systems are known to cause very bad FPS lag since they're (oddly enough) tied to the framerate. **Have you tried turning off the sounds?** | If you want to try some of the fixes (meant for lower-end systems), try turning off ragdolls and limit blood splatter with the `-lv` command-line option. *(Yes, it stands for 'Low Violence')*

Comment: Turned off all sound/audio, a few more fps added...

Comment: Do you play on lowest quality settings?  Integrated graphics on laptop CPUs can get hot quite quickly and cause the stutters (only speculating here). Have you tried playing on lower resolution (just to see if the FPS rate could get steady)?

Comment: this might help: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=268030869

Comment: Try running a bot match and testing to see if your connection has any effect on it. 
Does your laptop have an additional GPU that it uses? If so, there is a way to utilize the other GPU instead of the integrated graphics.

Comment: fixed it by doing the equivalent of a factory reset (clean install for windows 10, since I was going to do one anyways), and turns out, the version of my driver had huge problems, so I decided to go back down a version.

Comment: And, tanner, true what you say, but for me it wasn't a problem, as I watch my temp during gameplay, and can fell with my hand when the temp is +- 10^c. and resolution was 1366x786, thnx anyways.

Comment: Bad rice, as a guy with a laptop, you will never see a laptop with integrated graphics or APU's with another GPU installed internally. And no the connection has no affect, thanks anyways though.

Comment: tip for any of you guys for trying to help: Intel HD graphics XXXX series suck. 120 fps, minimalistic setting as possible on cs go. 20 fps minimum settings on bf3/bf4. Never buy a integrated graphics for gaming, hopefully with directx 12, it will help. And also bad rice, if you were asking if I had a "external" gpu, answer if no, but if any of you have a intel HD graphics card, I would recommend getting a external GPU adapter for your laptop and buying a GPU. (although you need another moniter/tv as well..)

Answer (score 1):

With laptops, framerate drops frequently occur if the laptop is not plugged in and charging. The fluxing you're talking about may be because you're playing CS:GO while its charge.

Just try it out and see.