# Extreme FPS Drops only in CS GO?

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive

my pc runs great with all games. I can easily run Fallout 4 on ultra, while playing cs on ultra or low I get maxxed FPS. However, I noticed in the beginning of the rounds, I tend to have 20-30 fps. Then back to 400 FPS. How is that even possible?

Are there any ways I can solve this issue? (I get 60 FPS constant on fallout 4, as it's locked to 60 FPS)

It goes from 400 FPS to 30 FPS, this happens around 5-6 times in a round. for periods of 2-3 seconds.

Issues of PC: PSU runs hot as I have placed the fan upside down. Other than that everything else stays cool.

Setup: AMD 8350, 280x, 8gb ram. Not too good of a pc, but 100% enough for cs go.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209578/extreme-fps-drop-in-counter-strike-global-offensive

Comment: Why don't you turn the PSU the right way?

Answer (score 1):

There are very many reasons this could be happening.
One of which is definitely your sound card drivers.

Try to notice if you get the lag when a specific sound is played or when a new sound appears again in the game. 
For example, I get lag spikes myself when I start the game at first. Then when some time passes and I haven't heard, say, smoke grenade sound, when I hear it I get lag spikes.

This is very annoying and the reason is probably my sound card as I have installed and uninstalled sound and graphics card drivers, neither of which have helped.

- Try to mess with your audio and graphics drivers.
- Lower your Hz from 'Sound' properties to CD, not DVD or Studio.

Also, try to be more specific with your problem. When *exactly* does this happen? How often?

Comment: It is probably not the sound card drivers. It is more likely that the game is loading sounds (or other things) from your hard drive when it is needed. That means your game is lagging the time is needed for the hard drive to load the "new" things in your RAM. SSDs perform better so your lag should be shorter.

Comment: I do have an SSD. I have tried installing it on my HDD aswell, same problem.

Answer (score 1):

While I wouldn't advise you to run your PSU upside down for an extended period of time, if you can run a much more taxing game without issues the issue is almost certainly a software one. I would try reinstalling the game as that is probably the easiest fix, and after that updating any audio or video drivers. Unfortunately none of this may work.

I had a very similar issue (lag when certain sound files played) with a game that turned out to be an audio codec issue. There are various tools for cleaning out codecs, but they are not perfect. The only way I could fix the issue was doing a full system restore to a point before the problem appeared. If this is unavailable to you might need to reinstall Windows and do a clean wipe. Though this is probably the most extreme measure to fix any software issue like this (so exhausting things like updating drivers and reinstalling the game are probably worth it) , it generally works with a higher probability than any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Getting 400 FPS is purely a waste of power and results in a lot of excess heat. If your GPU gets very hot, it will throttle down to prevent damage to hardware which explains your periodical FPS drops.

Anything higher than your monitors refresh rate won't make **any** difference to you as you won't be able to see the frames your GPU renders, because your monitor simply can't show them.

I'd recommend get your frame rate fixed to your monitor's refresh rate.

Comment: While most of the post is correct, I'd like to point out that you seem to be mistaking high refresh rate monitors for g-sync monitors (not mutually exclusive).

Comment: @Chippies Umm, I might have worded that part poorly (not a native speaker). I know they are completely 2 different things with different technologies. What part do I seem to be mistaking the G-Sync monitors with high refresh rate ones? I'd like to fix it.

Comment: The part where you say "unless of course you have a G-Sync monitor." implies that g-sync monitors can show fps above the refresh rate of the monitor. G-sync monitors synchronize the refresh rate to the fps, but it's still limited by the max refresh rate of the monitor, so a 60Hz monitor wouldn't be able to show more than 60 fps and a 144hz monitor wouldn't be able to show more than 144fps.

Comment: @Chippies turns out, I was mistaking the two. Updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out, today I learnt.

Answer (score -1):

It happens to me, I solve it by opening Nvidia control panel after starting the game(assuming you have nvidia video card).

Comment: What do you change in the control panel? If you just open it I am pretty sure nothing happens...

Answer (score -2):

Stop forcing your PC to run all at ultra some things PC cant handle because they might be bugged becasue they are new and not correctly developed and that can cause it!